# Регулярка на js "не искать внутри кавычек, но все выражение в кавычках - да"

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Всем доброго дня! В общем, нужно найти все слова (буквы и цифры), перед которыми стоит знак минус. Трудность в том, что если это находится где-то внутри кавычек - то искать не надо.
Примеры. 
    -словоКотороеНайдет этоеНет -этоСноваНадет
    -"этоНайдет полностью и меня и меня"
    "-аВот я ненужен" -аЯНужен
    "и я -неНужен"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что [получилось](http://regexr.com?38aql):

```
/(^|[\s\n])-(([^\s"'][^"']*?)(?=\s)|(["'])([^\s"'][^"']*?)\4)/g
```

Это **не** сработает

- "например -"для вот такой конструкции""
- "для -этого слова"

Перед выражением должен бы пробел, перевод строки или начало текста, а кавычки должны стоять прямо перед и сразу после текста. Это необходимое условие,иначе выражение, оказавшееся между двумя выражениями в кавычках, тоже будет пропускаться. По этой же причине нельзя отследить второе исключение из списка выше:

> @eicto, да, это пропустит, вы правы.
>   Но отслеживать кавычки обрамлённые
>   пробелами бессмысленно, потому как
>   такая форма проверки отсеит и текст не
>   заключённый в кавычки, а находящийся
>   между двумя фразами в кавычках, потому
>   остаётся предполагать, что кавычки
>   стоят прямо перед текстом, или сразу
>   после него. Так же пропустит "вот -это
>   слово", так как ни одна кавычка не
>   стоит рядом с ним. Если же сделать
>   проверку на наличие кавычек более
>   дотошной, учитывающей такой вариант,
>   то она отсеит -это "слово".

Выражение проверяет как двойные, так и одинарные кавычки.

Для более тщательной проверки стоит использовать несколько последовательных обработок текста, как [советует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298048#298148) @VenZell.

Comment: Отлично! Вроде то, что надо. А что делает экранированная четверка в конце?

Comment: @SomeName, повторяет запомненную четвёртую группу:

    (["'])

То есть выражению, в этой ветке, отвечает только текст находящийся между двумя одинаковыми кавычками: Если в скобках запомнено `"`, то на месте `\4` парсер будет искать `"`. По ссылке, что я дал в ответе, можно посмотреть, в том числе, какая группа выражения какой номер имеет (раздел под окошком с тестовым текстом). Это пригодится, чтобы вытащить текст именно из той группы что вам нужна.

Comment: @Risto, у вас ошибка в регулярка.  
В вашем же примере: "-аВот я ненужен" захватывается '"-аВот '

Comment: @VenZell, признавайтесь, вы прокляли мой регексп?) Парсер почему-то начал игнорировать первую скобку, хотя нормально её обрабатывал несколько часов назад.
@SomeName, работает, если удалить третью ветвь первой скобки:

    /(^|[\s\n])-(([^\s"'][^"']*?)(?:\s)|(["'])([^\s"'][^"']*?)\4)/g

Но может пропустить второе вхождение вашего шаблона, если их будет идти два подряд через пробел, проверьте на практике.

Comment: @Risto Да, пропускает -"этоНайдет полностью и меня и меня"  если перед ним только один пробел :(

Comment: "кавычка пробел минус слово пробел кавычка" не правильно работает по моему...

    -ЭтоСловоНайдет и " -ЭтоТожеНайдет аЭтоПропустит"

Comment: @eicto, да, это пропустит, вы правы. Но отслеживать кавычки обрамлённые пробелами бессмысленно, потому как такая форма проверки отсеит и текст не заключённый в кавычки, а находящийся между двумя фразами в кавычках, потому остаётся предполагать, что кавычки стоят прямо перед текстом, или сразу после него. Так же пропустит "вот -это слово", так как ни одна кавычка не стоит рядом с ним. Если же сделать проверку на наличие кавычек более дотошной, учитывающей такой вариант, то она отсеит -это "слово".

Comment: я из-за этого не стал свой вариант делать, без рекурсии тут нечего ловить.

Comment: @SomeName, последний вариант таки оставляет некоторые дыры, но больше одним регекспом уже не сделать. Самый эффективный вариант регекспа лецит в ответе, снабжённый моими комментариями. Надеюсь, что помог.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**: Второй раз переписал ответ.
Отказался от написания одной универсальной регулярки, написав вместо этого несколько фильтров.
**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/TP9fx/5/)**

```
Array.prototype.diff = function (a) {
    return this.filter(function (i) {
        return (a.indexOf(i) > -1) ? false : true;
    });
};

var string = 'неа -словоКотороеНайдет этоНет -этоСноваНадет " -это не нужно ? " -"этоНайдет полностью и меня и меня" -"-аВот я нужен" -аЯНужен "и я -неНужен" vs',
    badQuotes = string.match(/\-?"[^"]+"/g).diff(string.match(/\-"[^"]+"/g)),
    temp = '';

badQuotes.forEach(function (item) {
    temp = temp ? temp.replace(item, '') : string.replace(item, '');
});

var raw = temp.replace(/(\s+)/g, ' ').match(/(\-([^\-"\s]+)+|"[^"]+")/g),
    filtered = raw.map(function (el) {
        return el.replace(/^[\-"\s]?|[\-"\s]?$/g, '');
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

---

```
 [
  "словоКотороеНайдет",
  "этоСноваНадет",
  "этоНайдет полностью и меня и меня",
  "-аВот я нужен",
  "аЯНужен"
 ]
```

Comment: точна та-же проблема :) http://ideone.com/GMBH6a в php есть ещё рекурсия по группе, как раз  удобно тут использовать.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TP9fx/2/ :P

Comment: А-а-а! Обожаю регулярки! Сразу чувствуешь, как шестеренки скрипят... В процессе модификации.

Comment: там причем после 

    " -слово "  

ловится любое слово с минусом (не считая того, что заканчивается на кавычку), т.е. '" -\S "' не считается в кавычках

Comment: Теперь содержимое кавычек корректно фильтруется, насколько заметил.